# How to increment a particular column values by 1 using sequelize command in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

What I basically want to do is that, every time I enter a data, all other data's priority in my table should be incremented by 1 and then the newly entered data's priority should be set to 1.
In the below code I'm first counting the number of data(rows) , that would be my dataCount and I'm trying to increment the value of a column(priority) by one using the function 'upsert'. I do not know what this upsert function is, I just tried it, anyways my code is not working.
let dataCount = await this.testimonialRepository.count({});

```
  let data;
  if(dataCount>0){
    
    await this.testimonialRepository.upsert({priority:+1},{})
    data = await this.testimonialRepository.add({
      ...this.requestBody,
      status: Number(statusEnum.ACTIVE),
      createdBy: admin.id,
      priority: 1
    });
     
  }
  else{
    data = await this.testimonialRepository.add({
      ...this.requestBody,
      status: Number(statusEnum.ACTIVE),
      createdBy: admin.id,
      priority: 1
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update existing records then it's enough to use `update` instead of `upsert`. However if you want to increase a value of a certain column use `increment` method:

```js
await this.testimonialRepository.increment('priority', { by: 1})
```